# Which HttpURLConnection methods are sensible to re-try to Twitter?

Tags: java, android, http

The following java code runs in an IntentService; it works; it uploads an image to twitter.
I have coded it with a separate try-catch at each call that throws an IOException.
I have removed code at the ... spots to make it quicker to read.

```
try {
    con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(Constants.TWITTER_ENDPOINT_UPLOAD_MEDIA).openConnection();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

...

con.setDoOutput(true);
try {
    os = con.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(os);
try {
    write(out, boundary + "\r\n");
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My question is:
Does it make sense to put one or more of these calls inside a re-try loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    try {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(Constants.TWITTER_ENDPOINT_UPLOAD_MEDIA).openConnection();
        break;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        if (i < 3) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            reportErrorToCallingActivity();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And, if it does make sense, at which ones?
And, if for example I were to need to re-try at:

```
statusCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

how much code should I re-run: all the way back to openConnection?
I just can't figure this out from the documentation,
and I don't want to just guess at what to do. Hope you can help!

Comment: You know, you can just put all of that code inside one try/catch block. You don't need separate checks for each statement. You only have to catch the IOException once for the entire block of code.

Comment: Yes, but you loose information: exactly which method resulted in the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is probably greatly cut-down, but I think the giveaway here is that when you catch your `IOException`s all you do is log them to the console. In other words, your code doesn't know what to do, what state it (or the connection) is in, or how to proceed. Given that checking exception message text is bad practice, the exception type just doesn't give good enough information. In that case, the simplest and most honest thing is to rethrow the original exception in the hope that the calling code knows more / can handle the error better.

If, at any stage, you (or your code) are confident you can fully/largely deal with an exception, **then** have an explicit try/catch the way your current code does. But if you don't, your method should 'fess up' and declare that it `throws IOException` without trying to handle them at all. (Make sure you have a `finally` block to clean up any resources you've created in the process!)

Provided your method is honest and cleans up after itself, the calling method can potentially retry in a loop - as per your second code example. However, without any controls on retrying (number of attempts, backoff, etc.) and without any good guidance from the connection API, it's probably unwise to keep trying, potentially wasting resources, getting rate-limited, breaching T&Cs etc.

A better solution would be to obtain a Twitter access library that returns meaningful status messages, and that can potentially handle its own retries.

**Edit:**

By far the most useful line is `statusCode = con.getResponseCode();` which gives you a value you can check against [Twitter's Error Codes list](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes). In general, if you get 2xx back, your request has succeeded, 4xx means your code has done something wrong, 5xx means Twitter has done something wrong. At least that lets you adjust your error message if you - as you probably should - bail out rather than try to work around it.

It looks like 420 and 429 best indicate that you can retry. However, you will need to do so much more carefully than just repeating your request in an endless loop. You should definitely read the [Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting) doc for guidance.

Comment: It doesn't help me to throw these exceptions, because I'd be throwing them to my own code, which of course is no wiser. BTW, I have coded this twitter stuff using the twitter4j library, but it's really big and blows my dex limit.Aso, it treats these exceptions just as you describe: it passes them up to me, and so I'm still at the same impasse: I don't know if a re-try is sensible or just a waste.

Comment: Might be worth posting your calling code (or some of it), so we can see how the t4j integration is being done. But what you say, I think, confirms my point: that if you aren't in a position to handle the exceptions, you aren't in a position to attempt retries, so you should let them propagate to anyone that can handle them. Which should probably be the part of your code that has to show a 'Sorry, there was an error' message to your user.

Comment: Hi Regan: First, thanx for helping. I can't go back to the twitter4j code because it busts my dex limit. So, I have to stick with the current code. It works great except from time to time there's a network failure. I  report failures (by broadcast) back to the boss Activity, and it categorizes the errors so that it gives User the best information I can come up with. It comes down to this: I want to go the extra mile and  retry appropriately, so that I can succeed at the upload and not have to give up and disappoint my User with "Sorry..."

Comment: Ahh, but now you're talking about situations twitter reports once you've gotten through to them. I have those covered. [BTW, they're not all errors. If User gets rate-limited, that's his problem, not mine; I just report it.] What I'm talking about are network errors that prevent me from getting through to twitter in the first place, and retrying those as appropriate.

Comment: See what others suggest, but IMO the very fact that we can't state what these presumably transient network errors are suggests that we shouldn't aspire to handle them, just display a generic error message.

Comment: So here's my plan: I'm exhaustively coding re-tries, Logs, and throws at every method. Then, after several hundred runs I might get an idea of what failures occur and which can be re-tried. After that, I'll try to answer my question myself.